# Callout lines grouping on Labels with the same name

Tags: qgis, callout

I am using callout lines to take the label away from the point to make my maps easier to read.

Running QGIS 3.4.11

I am using this expression:

```
make_line(
  make_point($x, $y),
  make_point( "auxiliary_storage_labeling_positionx" , "auxiliary_storage_labeling_positiony" )
)
```

Many of my labels have the same names in this instance 'wildflower meadow'. When I move one 'wildflower meadow' label all the call out lines attached to a wildflower meadow labels become attached that one label.

How can I make each call out line separate to each label even if they have the same name?

I am using QGIS 3.4.11..

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The solution to your problem is to select, when you move the first label, as Primary Key for the Auxiliary Storage a field with Unique Value, like the ID and not the field that contains your label.

The selection of a field that contains double attributes as primary key, determinate that all the auxiliary coordinates with a common key, will be stored as same point.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic Val. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. If you are happy with the solution please check the answer as accepted to help the people to know it is a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

For reference -- if you upgrade to QGIS 3.10 or later, then you'll get access to an inbuilt callout option which doesn't rely on geometry generators. It's much easier to use and doesn't run into situations like this.